# Wrong region when map view is subclassed

Tags: ios, mkmapview

If I subclass mkmapview I am unable to programmatically zoom in to the full extent. If I do not subclass, zooming works as expected.

My mkmapview subclass:

MyMapView.h

```
     #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface MyMapView : MKMapView  {

    }

    -(id)initWithLocation:(NSInteger)location;

    @end
```

MyMapView.m

```
    #import "MyMapView.h"

    @implementation MyMapView

    -(id)initWithLocation:(NSInteger)location; {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
        }
        return self;
    }
```

my viewcontroller.m:

```
    MyMapView *theMap = [[MyMapView alloc] initWithLocation:0];
    theMap.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
    [self.view addSubview:theMap];            

    float lat = 33.78;
    float lon = -84.56;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (newCenter, 10, 10);
    [theMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

The resulting map view region is zoomed out much farther than I want. I know the 10 meters is probably tighter than can fit, but I expect the map to be zoomed in as tightly as it can. After the map finishes zooming, I can still manually zoom in 2 more levels.

I could fix the whole thing by including all the code in my main view controller, but I want to abstract the map a bit and keep my viewcontroller.m file cleaner and smaller.

What stupid mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), you should not subclass MKMapView.

> Although you **should not subclass the MKMapView class** itself, you can get information about the map view’s behavior by providing a delegate object.

Comment: Is there some other way to keep all the mapview code in another file?

Comment: Sure. You can use [categories or extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Comment: I think category is what I really want. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Making a mkmapview category didn't solve my problem. The resulting region is still zoomed out further than it should be.

Comment: You won't be making a category on MKMapView. Instead, you'll make a category on your view controller, and all the code that interacts with the MKMapView will be there. Also, make sure you change your references from your custom MKMapView sublcass (`MyMapView`) back to the default MKMapView class.